Generating a free module
Let $R$ be a ring with $1$ and let $M$ be an $R$-module. Let $A \subseteq M$. Is it true that the following are equivilent.

$A$ is linearly independent.
$R \cong Ra$ and $$\sum_{a \in A}Ra = \bigoplus_{a \in A}Ra$$
Let $F(A)$ be the free module on the set $A$. Then
$$\sum_{a \in A}Ra \cong F(A)$$

I think I proved that (1) and (2) are equivilent and that (1) implies (3) but I'm not sure how to prove that (3) implies the other two.
